# Eclipse: Exception (nullpointer) while running spring boot maven project via boot dashboard

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am getting the following exception when I am trying to run spring boot maven project from boot dashboard

```
!ENTRY Activator 4 0 2018-09-24 16:46:55.345
!MESSAGE NullPointerException: null
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClassifierManager.getClassifierClasspathProvider(MavenClassifierManager.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.addProjectEntries(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.addMavenClasspathEntries(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.resolveClasspath0(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider$1.call(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider$1.call(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.resolveClasspath(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.RuntimeClasspathProvider.resolveClasspath(RuntimeClasspathProvider.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.resolveRuntimeClasspath(JavaRuntime.java:1719)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getClasspathAndModulepath(AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:459)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch.BootLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getClasspathAndModulepath(BootLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaLaunchDelegate.launch(JavaLaunchDelegate.java:77)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch.AbstractBootLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(AbstractBootLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:333)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch.BootLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(BootLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
```

Comment: Please try to build from plain command line without IDE and afterwards try to start from command line the Spring Boot App.